# Change GeoNetwork default CRS from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:27700

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, geonetwork, united-kingdom

I am a relatively new convert to the GeoNetwork (on 2.6) and presently setting up a server in the UK but have been having issues with the crs code used in proj. I think this is where I need to make the changes but correct me if wrong!

What I am trying to do is to project the data in the "mapViewer" and "mapSearch" (within config-gui.xml) in a projection other than epsg:4326, which for my region is epsg:27700 (the UK), so that when a viewer looks at the map the data are projected in a manner familiar to the viewer.  However, when I set the crs code to epsg:27700 I find that the map elements of GN do not load.

Are there some other files that I should be modifying?

Comment: So your data is saved in 4326 but you'd like to have it displayed in 27700? Are you sure GeoNetwork supports on-the-fly re-projection?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm having a similar problem. @underdark- the problem is that geonetwork is set up by default to display data in EPSG 4326, but for the UK we want it in EPSG 27700, as that's what our data is projected in, and we would also like a more UK-focussed extent, rather than the whole world. You can add the additional CRS in config-gui.xml, but there are other elements that also need changing to get the extents of the maps and the background mapping to display correctly. @mark- I'm working through this as well and if I get anywhere I will let you know!

Comment: I see. So the question should be "How to change GeoNetwork's default CRS from EPSG:4326 to 27700"

Comment: Hi underdark - I wanted to be relatively generic with the question so that it would fit all queries relating to changing default the default CRS and therefore be spotted by more willing knowledgeable experts.